# Gradlew installDebug win8.1 (React Native)

Tags: android, react-native

Did cd in my directory with my react-native project. I have android studio running and a emulator. But when I run (`react-native run-android`) seems not to work. I get the following error. I ran clean another tips but still no success.

```
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:634:13)
```

Comment: can you post a bit more of error log, because I think actual error will be somewhat above this log.

Comment: have you solved?